# php finding match in a string

Tags: php, strpos

When coding in PHP, if I need to match phrase inside a string I use

`if(strpos("findmeinstring","findme")>0)`

but strpos is not the correct method, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
if (strpos("findmeinstring","findme") !== false)
```

From [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please
>   read the section on [Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use [the ===
>   operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: Hi, thanks do you know how to achieve the same result with preg_match?

Comment: To find a simple string, there is no need for ```preg_match```. Use ```preg_match``` only if you need pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

I think [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is the correct method for this. But you should use ===

```
if(strpos("findmeinstring","findme") !== false)
```